# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity after update to latest versions

Tags: android, android-theme

I have an app that used to work several months ago which I just compiled after updating various implementation files with the latest versions. Now when I try to run it I get "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity". Well, I know what that means but in this case that's exactly what I am doing. Obviously something changed in one of those implementation files (androidX I'm guessing) and it's seeing things differently than it used to.

Anyway, here is the relevant bits of info. Anyone see what it is I need to change?

```
<application
            android:name=".MyApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
            tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
                android:name=".ui.StartScreenActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_start_screen"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.android.myapp.ui.StartScreenActivity.onCreate(StartScreenActivity.kt:32)
```

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        actionBar?.hide()

        setContentView(com.android.myapp.R.layout.activity_start_screen)
```

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/splash"
             tools:context=".ui.StartScreenActivity">
</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see, I'm using Theme.AppCompat for both the application and the Activity already. Not sure what else I could do. I've tried restarting Android Studio and various other things to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, seems to be a bug with the MaterialComponents 1.1.0 version.
I updated to `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06` and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

try removing actionBar?.hide() from your code and use:

Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar instead of Theme.AppCompat as your activity style

Comment: Thank you for trying, but that didn't do it. This is really odd. It should work.